# Usage of progesterone for recurrent miscarriages

Tags: obstetrics, endocrinology, miscarriage

On news and pregnancy sites* (which are notoriously full of things not supported by science), I have read that progesterone is sometimes given to women suffering from recurrent miscarriages (3 or more miscarriages) in some countries. But I am also reading that no medical organization recommends this treatment.

Is there any evidence that progesterone helps prevent recurrent miscarriages, provided the woman does not actually have low progesterone levels?

( * [Daily Mail article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2692055/Can-taking-simple-hormone-prevent-heartache-miscarriage.html)  and lots and lots of people in forums such as Babycenter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I believe I can answer my own question, even though it is a somewhat dissatisfying one.

There is no indication that progesterone supplementation helps prevent  sporadic miscarriages (women have not had three or more pregnancy losses before).

> However, in patients with three or more consecutive miscarriages immediately preceding their current pregnancy, empiric progestogen administration may be of some potential benefit.

There is currently a large study underway to test this effect, however, no results have been published yet.

*edited a month later*

The results of that large trial were published at the end of November 2015.

> The study of 826 women with previously unexplained recurrent miscarriage showed that those who received progesterone treatment in early pregnancy were no less likely to miscarry than those who received a placebo (or dummy treatment). This was true whatever their age, ethnicity, medical history and pregnancy history.

From the study:

> Progesterone therapy in the first trimester of pregnancy did not result in a significantly higher rate of live births among women with a history of unexplained recurrent miscarriages.

[A Randomized Trial of Progesterone in Women with Recurrent Miscarriages](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1504927)

*Sources and further reading*:

[Evidence-based management of recurrent miscarriages](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4229790/)

[Promise study](http://www.miscarriageassociation.org.uk/information/research/the-promise-trial/)

[Progestogen for preventing miscarriage](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18425891) (meta analysis of studies showing no impact on sporadic miscarriages, but effect for recurrent miscarriages)